# Cannot destructure property `variableName` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

The original error say's: `Cannot destructure property 'firstime' of 'undefined' or 'null'`.

I am developing web-base desktop application for Windows pc using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [Electron](https://electronjs.org/).
I am trying to persist some data in user data directory, I found the idea and using the same approach in [this](https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/how-to-store-user-data-in-electron-3ba6bf66bc1e) link.

Writing and fetching data works fine, however the error occurred at the first time of fetching the data.

here is the code for `UserPreferences` class

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

class UserPreferences {
    constructor(opts) {
            const userDataPath = (electron.app || electron.remote.app).getPath('userData');
            this.path = path.join(userDataPath, opts.configName + '.json');
            this.data = parseDataFile(this.path, opts.defaults);
            console.log(userDataPath); 
        }
    get(key) {
            return this.data[key];
        }
    set(key, val) {
        this.data[key] = val;
        fs.writeFileSync(this.path, JSON.stringify(this.data));
    }
}

function parseDataFile(filePath, defaults) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
    } catch (error) {
        return defaults;
    }
}

module.exports = UserPreferences;
```

and here's the function for using the `UserPreferences` class

```
function isFirstTime() {
            try{
                const userAccount = new UserPreferences({
                configName: 'fipes-user-preferences', // We'll call our data file 'user-preferences'
                defaults: {

                    user: { firstime: true, accountid: 0, profileid: '' }
                }
                });

                var { firstime, accountid, profileid } = userAccount.get('user');

                if (firstime === true) {  //check if firstime of running application
                    //do something
                } else {
                    //do something
                }   
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }
```

the error occurred on the line where I am checking weather the `firstime` is true or false.

Comment: `firstname` is nowhere in the code you posted... is that really all the relevant code? What line does the error occur at?

Comment: I would also like to add that including 'I found this idea at this webadres' hurts the longevity of your question and should be avoided.

Comment: sorry, typo error.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - it was actually `firstime` it's a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version of `UserPreferences` which will be more natural to use as you write your code. You can create it like you see in `isFirstTime`.

```
console.debug(userPreferences[accountId]);
userPreferences[accountId] = 1;
```

This is preferred because there is no reason for a developer not to treat `UserPreferences` as an object. Another good idea would be separating the writing to the file into a separate `flush` method, in case you are updating preferences often.

```
const electron = require("electron");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

class UserPreferences {
    constructor(defaultPrefs, pathToPrefs) {
        const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app;
        this.pathToPrefs = path.join(app.getPath("userData"), pathToPrefs + ".json");

        try {
            this.store = require(this.pathToPrefs);
        }
        catch (error) {
            this.store = defaultPrefs;
        }
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get(target, property) {
                return target.store[property];
            },
            set(target, property, value) {
                target.store[property] = value;
                fs.writeFileSync(target.pathToPrefs, JSON.stringify(target.store));
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = UserPreferences;
```

Here is a pure version of `isFirstTime`, that should do what you want, while maintaining a more robust method of checking for `isFirstTime`. The check can also be changed so check whether `lastSignIn` is equal to `createdAt` (with appropriate defaults, of course).

```
function isFirstTime() {
    const account = new UserPreferences({
        user: {
            accountId: 0,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            lastSignIn: null,
            profileId: ""
        }
    }, "fipes-user-preferences");

    const {lastSignIn} = account;

    return lastSignIn === null;
}
```

Comment: can you explain this part `return lastSignIn === null;`? Thanks!

Comment: why do you have to make an equal to null?

Comment: how do you set the value using your code? when I tried `account.set('user', {accountId: value,createdAt: new Date(),lastSignIn: value, profileId: value});` it say's `account.set is not a function`.

Comment: and instead of `const account = UserPreferences` I have to use `new` so it should be `const account = new UserPreferences`.

Comment: `return lastSignIn === null` will return true when you initialize the account with the above preferences. Accordingly, you would update that value whenever the user signs in, meaning it would no longer be null.

Comment: And to do the above with this class, you can do this: `account.user = {…}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all do not declare a object like `var { firstTime, .. }` like this. if you do this `firstTime` will be a property of an anonymous object. That you can never access elsewhere. Check what is the output of `userAccount.get('user')` function, output contain some object like `{ firstime: true, accountid: "test", profileid: "test" }` then try this. Hope this helps you.

```
var result=userAccount.get('user');
if(result.firstTime===true){
  //your code
}
```

Comment: what is the output of userAccount.get('user')  function?